# Chart.js radar chart ticks are hidden behind the graph

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Is it possible to bring the "ticks" of the Chart.js radar graph to the foreground so that they would be on top of the graph itself?

[image]

I don't see anything related to this issue in the official documentation.

Method that renders this:

```
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'polarArea',
        data: {
    labels: ['Silver', 'Palladium', 'Platinum', 'Gold'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Points',
        pointRotation: 45,
        backgroundColor: [
          color(this.chartColors.grey).rgbString(),
          color(this.chartColors.green).rgbString(),
          color(this.chartColors.blue).rgbString(),
          color(this.chartColors.yellow).rgbString(),
        ],
        data: [0, 0, 0, 0],
        borderWidth: 0,
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
      }
    ],
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    animation: {
      animateRotate: true
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0
      }
    },
    scale: {
      ticks: {
        fontColor: '#000000',
        mirror: true,
      }
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'top'
    },
  }
});
```

One workaround is to make these fill colours transparent like so:

```
color(this.chartColors.yellow).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
```

...this way the ticks would be somewhat acceptably visible. However, I'd rather have them fully saturated. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the `scale.ticks.z` option as as [documented here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#tick-configuration).

```
scale: {
  ticks: {
    ...
    z: 1
  }
},
```

> z-index of tick layer. Useful when ticks are drawn on chart area. Values <= 0 are drawn under datasets, > 0 on top.

Please have a look at your amended code below:

```js
const chart = new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'polarArea',
        data: {
    labels: ['Silver', 'Palladium', 'Platinum', 'Gold'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Points',
        pointRotation: 45,
        backgroundColor: ['grey', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'],
        data: [3, 4, 8, 9],
        borderWidth: 0,
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    animation: {
      animateRotate: true
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0
      }
    },
    scale: {
      ticks: {
        fontColor: '#000000',
        mirror: true,
        z: 1
      }
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'top'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you so much! Somehow I missed that part in the documentation.